# How to add marker in sequence editor via python?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I found the timeline_markers function to add markers in the timeline like:

```
import bpy
scene = bpy.data.scenes['Scene']
scene.timeline_markers.new('F_01', frame=1)
```

but I can't find the similar function deal with sequence editor

Comment: Well, the data path i think is scene.sequence_editor.markers, but I will check.

Comment: timeline and vse share the same markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Lemon said, the Video Sequence Editor and the Timeline Editor share the same markers. So, your code from above should work for the VSE.

- Open the Video Editing workspace and add a movie strip. Then add the
  Scripting workspace (click on the + next to the tab Render and choose
  General > Scripting.
- Create a new script (click on the button + New at the top) and paste
  your code from above.
- Run the script (click on triangle at the top).
- Switch to the Video Editing workspace. There you will find the marker
  F_01 at frame 1.

If you need more details about how to create a script; see https://vse-docs.readthedocs.io/extra-tools/python/scripting-workspace.html#how-to-use-the-script-editor-efficiently